# Import html to lotus notes richtext using java

Tags: java, lotus-notes, lotus-domino, sign, richtext

I would like to create a notes mail from some html  source (with possibly inline image and attachments) using java through DIIOP.   I tried to use mime item to do that, but sign and encrypt would need internet certs. So rich text seems to be the only choice,  but I could not find any java API to import html into richtext.  In notes client GUI, one can import from text/html.  And also I noticed that MIME mail exported from inbox are "Itemized by DIIOP Server".  Is there any way I can programmatically import html into lotus notes message so that sign and encrypt can be used with Lotus Notes internal certs.

Thanks and Regards,

Shing

Comment: Are you sure that the MIME body is what is causing it to require the internet certs? I.e., are you putting fully distinguished notes user names in the address fields, or are you putting in internet email addresses?

Comment: I only put fully distinguished notes user names in the address fields , no internet email address. But it seems that whenever I use MIME and sign and/or encrypt, I got NotesException.
NotesException: Notes error: The cryptographic key was not found.

Comment: Okay. I understand now. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to encrypt using Java via DIIOP, but you can't sign that way.

You need a private key in order to sign a message or document. The low-level Notes APIs expect the private key to be located in the current ID file for the session. When you are using DIIOP. Your Java code is running locally and it does not have access to your user ID file. The low-level Notes APIs don't run on the same machine that the Java is running on. There usually isn't even a Notes or Domino installation on the code where the Java code is running, so the code for the low-level APIs isn't even available to the JVM.

In a DIIOP configuraiton, the low-level Notes API code is running on the Domino server. The only ID file it has access to is the server ID file, and it will not allow you to sign using the server's private key.

Comment: But if I create a document using richtext item only using Java via DIIOP, I can sign and/or encrypt, but no so with MIME item.  
I tried import some internet cert into the Lotus client, and then send mime document from Local, I noticed that the document are signed using the internet cert.  But we do not plan to use internet email cert for sending mail within Notes.

Comment: I can't explain that, but I have a guess. You cannot sign without reading a private key from an ID file. I am 100% certain of that. Perhaps with Rich Text the Java API ignores the problem - i.e, it does not sign it, but also does not throw an error. But with MIME, the code path in the Java API is different and it throws the error. That's my best guess.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually find a solution, abeit rather hacky.  create a document using MIME, then save to database, then close the session. The open a new session, and get the saved document, it is converted to richtext by the Domino Server, but there are some traces of MIME, export to DXL using DXLExporter. In the exported DXL, remove the items "MIME_Version" and "$MIMETrack". Inline image of type other than jpg and gif (png and gif) are not handled properly, have to play around the XML DOM a bit to fix it, then import the fixed DXL using DXLImporter, and there you have a converted Richtext document, rather like what you get from importing HTML file in Note Client GUI.  Better than none.